# Hide options with no results

Tags: views

I have a view block that displays products (a content type). This view uses AJAX and has an exposed filter to sort results per taxonomy terms (product categories) in specific contexts.

I want the exposed filter to hide options with no results (since it is useless to show them if there are not results). I thought there could be an easy way to it, but I cannot find it.

I have already find these links, but I really want to exclude custom modules if possible.

- https://ffwagency.com/blog/limiting-select-options-for-exposed-filter
- [How to make exposed filters to hide filed with no value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137793/how-to-make-exposed-filters-to-hide-field-with-no-value)

Comment: A lot of time later, i found the famous :
https://www.drupal.org/project/selective_better_exposed_filters/issues/3256177